# Split column with range [a-b] into (b - a + 1) rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with columns:

```
| School | Room | Period | Class |
```

Values for Period can be of the sort:

- 1
- 2
- 3
- 1-3
- 3-4

For classes spanning more than one period (eg 1-3), I need to create records for period 1,2,3. So basically insert 2 more and add a column with the appropriate period.

Current state:

```
School   Room  Period Class
Elm High  100    1     Math
Elm High  101   1-3    Eng
```

Desired State:

```
School   Room  Period Class
Elm High  100    1     Math
Elm High  101    1     Eng
Elm High  101    2     Eng
Elm High  101    3     Eng
```

Any ideas? I can only use T-SQL/SQL for this.

Comment: What's your sql server version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your periods are only one digit, here is a simple approach using a recursive CTE:

```
with t as (
      select v.*
      from (values ('Elm High', 100, '1', 'Math'),
                   ('Elm High', 101, '1-3', 'Eng')
           ) v(School, Room, Period, Class)
     ),
     cte as (
      select school, room, convert(int, left(period, 1))  as period, class, convert(int, right(period, 1)) as period_end
      from t
      union all
      select school, room, period + 1, class, period_end
      from cte
      where period < period_end
     )
select school, room, period, class
from cte
order by school, room, period;
```

And a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4ae0cb802b98d1c4e25eb51bd00360d4).

It is not hard to expand this to periods greater than 9.  But that seems like a lot of periods for a school day.

Comment: That works! How would this be expanded to periods greater than 9?
Thanks again and sorry for the late reply.

Comment: @lazycamper . . . You just need to change the way the string is initially split to get the bounds.